# Is an idempotent logical expression considered to be in conjunctive normal form?

Tags: logic, idempotents, conjunctive-normal-form

Is $$A \lor B \lor A$$ technically in conjunctive normal form?

Or must we apply the idempotent law for it to be in CNF?

$$A \lor B \lor A \equiv A \lor B$$?

Comment: I would say a CNF is any conjunction of disjunctions of literals (including the special case where there is just one conjunct). So there is no requirement to eliminate duplicated literals in one of the disjunctions. A possible alternative would be to require no duplicates and no candidates for a resolution step, but I don't think many authors do that (as they want CNFs for the input to the resoluton process, not just the output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF), there is no explicit restriction against having duplicate literals in the same clause. So, a formula such as $A \vee B \vee A$ is indeed in CNF even if it is not simplified to include the fewest terms and connectives.